# Can differences between 2 copies of the same serialized object be determined?

Tags: java, serialization

Suppose we possess 2 serialized copies of an object.

**Q1.** I wanted to know whether the state of an object can be compared with its prior state.

**Q2** If yes, can we find out precisely which class variables have been changed ?

**Q3** If the answer to the 2nd question is yes, can we perform some sort of "synchronization" to change only the modified class variables ?

Comment: This is a really broad question, but for starters, it would at least help if you told us *how* you were serializing objects. That said, in general, the cleanest, most robust approach (particularly to Q2 and Q3) would be to deserialize, perform necessary comparisons/syncs, then reserialize.

Comment: Hi Jason. We serialize objects at a client and send them to a server. At the server, some method execution may end up modifying the state variables. Now, we need to synchronize the changed member variables with its counterpart at the client. (this is being done for Android, actually).

Comment: I said "how" not "when"... the fact that you serialize on a client isn't really useful information. Are you using `ObjectOutputStream`? XStream? A custom bean-based thing? Hibernate? If you're going to ask vague questions like this here, especially when you haven't shown what you've tried so far, you really need to make it so that we don't have to pull teeth to get information.

Comment: Yes, we're using ObjectOutputStream to transmit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to check state of object is using

```
PropertyChangeSupport and PropertyChangeListener
```

You can go through the below link for how to write PropertyChangeListener for particular bean.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html

Comment: Hi Solution. Thanks for the informative reply. One doubt: Does PropertyChangeListener impose some performance penalty ? (because it always runs in the background).

Comment: No Abhishek, It will not affect on performance. It is working as same as other listener working, for Example onClickListener.

Comment: OK. So, I'll use PropertyChangeListener and instead of transmitting the entire object, only transmit the changed values back to the client. Hope it saves bandwidth.

Comment: Yes, this is the right way to do. If this answer help in implementing than please do up-vote or accept this as your answer. thanks.